# Effect of a diet

Tags: statistics

I am studying the effect of five artificial diets on some parameters in fly larvae development, trying to find out which is more appropriate for larval development. Each day I started a batch with each diet, and I added the same amount of eggs. Ten days later I removed the larvae from the assay. For each diet, I measured two parameters: deviation percentage and individual weight of the larvae. In this way, for 20 days I have obtained information from 20 batches from the five treatments.

The deviation percentage reflects the positive or negative deviation, after counting the larvae obtained, with respect to the estimated larvae (from the initial eggs). The individual weight of the larvae was obtained by selecting a sample of 500 larvae.

I had thought to analyze the data using Least significant difference (LSD) test following a significant F test (P ⱕ 0.05) to separate mean differences between diet treatments.

I've noticed something, though. When for some reason (for example because larvae escape), the deviation is very high, the individual weight of the larvae is higher. It is obvious, because there is less competition for the same amount of food, not because the nutritional value of the diet. In the most extreme cases it is easy to detect faulty batches. But is it possible that I can compensate or eliminate this effect by lack (or excess) of competition in the batches? Could you detect it?

Thank you and a cordial greeting.
Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Fisher's LSD is intended as a *secondary* test to establish the pattern of
differences among treatment means $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots \mu_5$ *provided*
an ANOVA has rejected the null hypothesis that all five treatment means
are equal.

The ANOVA has five treatment groups $g = 5$ with $n = 4$ replications in each
group. You would need to have the five group sample means $\bar Y_i$
and the five group sample variances $\S^2_i$ (or the original data) in order
to make a one-factor ANOVA table ($g-1=4$ degrees of freedom among groups, and
$g(n-1) = 15$ degrees of freedom, with total degrees of freedom $ng-1 = 19.$
Then, if the F-test finds that there are significant differences,
you could use Fisher's LSD procedure.

From what you say, it seems you may have different variances among the
five groups. In that case you may need to transform your data to standardize
variances, or to do a test that is not sensitive to heterogeneity of
variances. In any case, it may turn out to be better to use the Bonferroni method
of multiple comparisons instead of Fisher's LSD.

If you can post the five group sample means and five group standard deviations
*and* leave me a Comment,
I can take a look within the next few days to see what kind of analysis may be appropriate. (Or maybe someone else will take a look sooner.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Finally I've selected 4 diets. Here are the raw data with means and standard deviations: https://goo.gl/bBKZ2V

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make sense of these data. They seem to have been 'processed' somehow. Might be able to make sense of weight gains. Also, I would have to edit all of the commas to periods and get rid of all the %-signs before I could import these into any software. // If you feel the original weight gains are meaningful, and you are willing to supply them in plain text along rows: in a format such as `Mix1 = c(34.5, 57.5, 28.3, ...)`, and so on, then maybe I could make sense of them.

Comment: Sorry, here you have the csv files (data separate with comma): https://goo.gl/rDczjJ